# Contractibility of convex set

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, topological-vector-spaces

Suppose that $\Omega$ is a convex open subset of an infinite dimensional vector space $E$ such that $\Omega$ is not contained in any finite dimensional subspace of $E$.
Let $Q_m\subset \Omega$ denote a set of $m\in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$ distinct points.

> **Question:**
>   Is the space $\Omega\setminus Q_m$ contractible?

**Added later:**
Assume that for any set $Q_m'$ of $m$ distinct points $E\setminus Q'_m$ is contractible (I believe that this is true, see my answer below).
By "blowing up $\Omega$ like a balloon" we get a homeomorphism $\varphi$ from the convex open set $\Omega$ to $E$.
More precisely, fix $x_0\in\Omega$ and for any open interval $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ let $\varphi_I:I\to \mathbb{R}$ be a (suitable) homeomorphism.
Now, define $\varphi:\Omega \to E$ by $$\varphi(x):=\begin{cases}\varphi_{\Omega\cap \mathbb{R}\cdot (x-x_0)}(x), \text{ if } x\neq x_0 \\ x_0 , \text{ if } x= x_0.\end{cases}$$
(I know that the definition of $\varphi$ is not formally correct but I think that the idea is clear.)
Restricting $\varphi$ to $\Omega\setminus Q_m$ we get a homeomorphism between $\Omega\setminus Q_m$ and $E\setminus \varphi(Q_m)$.
By assumption $E\setminus \varphi(Q_m)$ is contractible and hence $\Omega\setminus Q_m$ is also contractible.

Is the intuition behind this heuristic argument any good?
Can it be made into a complete and rigorous argument?

Comment: [Kuiper's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuiper%27s_theorem) has it's roots in the fact that the unit sphere $S^{\infty}$ in infinite dimensional Hilbert space is contractible. The unit ball is convex and removing a point gives a set homotopic to the unit sphere so maybe that's a good place to start.

Comment: @TomHarris: Thanks.

Comment: What are you assuming about the surrounding topological vector space? Open convex subsets are homeomorphic to the whole space $X$, and if $X$ admits a continuous norm then $X \setminus K$ is homeomorphic to $X$ whenever $K$ is compact (but there may be much easier proofs of what you want). A reference is Bessaga and Pelczynski, Selected topics in infinite-dimensional topology, chapter III, §5.

Comment: @Martin : Thanks a lot for your comment and also for the reference. I'll definitely check it out. I suspect that the surrounding vector space is a Fréchet space. So, do you think that the answer to my original question is affirmative?

Comment: Definitely yes if the space is a separable Fréchet space. By a deep theorem of Anderson and Kadec these are all homeomorphic to $\ell_2$. Deleting a compact set from $\ell_2$ does not change the homeomorphism type, as I pointed out. Thus, every open convex set minus finitely many points is contractible in a separable Fréchet space. There must be much better (simpler and more explicit) solutions for your problem, but I hope it helps to know that it is true.

Comment: In my previous comment I implicitly assumed "infinite-dimensional" throughout.

Comment: @Martin : Thank you, this helps a lot! Did you spot any problems/errors in my sketch that $\Omega\setminus Q_m$ is homeomorphic to $E\setminus \varphi(Q_m)$? Because this together with the fact that $E\setminus \varphi(Q_m)$ is contractible (for which I have an elementary argument as well) gives a simple and explicit proof that $\Omega\setminus Q_m$ is contractible, right?

Comment: No, no problem at all. I would assume $0 \in \Omega$ and write the homeomorphism with $E$ as $x \mapsto \frac{x}{1-p_\Omega(x)}$ where $p_\Omega(x) = \inf\{\lambda \gt 0 \mid x \in \lambda \Omega\}$ is the [Minkowksi functional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_functional) on $E$ corresponding to $\Omega$. // I was trying to fill in what seemed to be missing: contractibility of $E \setminus Q_m'$, but if you have an elementary argument for that, this is surely much better than what I proposed. I'd be interested in seeing this argument. I suggest that you post this as an answer.

Comment: @Martin : Thanks, the Minkowski functional looks pretty nice. As you suggested I've posted a sketch of the argument as an answer below. Please let me know if you think it is correct or not.

Comment: I will take a look, but I'm quite busy right now. I'll try to find some time during the next 24 hours.

Answer (score 2):

Following the suggestion of Martin I'll post an answer to my own question. I would appreciate some feedback. Please let me know if you notice any errors.

Let $Q'_m\subset E$ be a set of $m\in \mathbb{N}$ distinct points.

> **Claim:** $E\setminus Q'_m$ is contractible.

*Proof:*
Write $E$ as $E\cong W\oplus V$ where $W\subset E$ is a finite dimensional subspace containing $Q'_m$.
Let $\Phi:W\oplus V \to W\oplus V$ be a linear map such that $\Phi|_W=id_W$ and $\Phi|_V$ has no non-zero eigenvalues. (For example $\Phi|_V$ could be chosen as $(v_1,v_2,v_3,\ldots)\mapsto (0,v_1,v_2,v_3,\ldots)$.)
The map $\Phi$ gives rise to an isomorphism from $E$ to a genuine subspace $im(\Phi)\subsetneq E$.
It also induces a map $\Phi:E\setminus Q'_m\to E\setminus Q'_m$.
Now, $\Phi_t:E\setminus Q'_m\to E\setminus Q'_m$ defined by
$$\Phi_t(x):=(1-t)x+t\Phi(x)\quad t\in [0,1]$$
is a homotopy from $id_{E\setminus Q'_m}$ to $\Phi$.
Pick $x_0\notin im(\Phi)\cup Q'_m$.
Then $\Psi_t:E\setminus Q'_m\to E\setminus Q'_m$ given by
$$ \Psi_t(x):=(1-t)\Phi(x)+tx_0\quad t\in [0,1]$$
is a homotopy from $\Psi_0=\Phi$ to the constant map $\Psi_1\equiv x_0$.
Hence, $E\setminus Q'_m$ is contractible.$\qquad\square$

This claim together with the fact that $\Omega\setminus Q_m$ is homeomorphic to $E\setminus Q'_m$ (see the comments by Martin and my argument in the question) shows that $\Omega\setminus Q_m$ is contractible.

*I'd like to thank Martin for his helpful comments.*

Comment: Why is there a *continuous* linear map $\Phi$ on $E$ having all the properties needed? Note that writing $(v_1,v_2,v_3, \dots) \mapsto (0,v_1,v_2,v_3)$ makes sense in a Hilbert space, but not for a general topological vector space $E$ (without further hypotheses).

Comment: I think what I'm really feeling uncomfortable with is that you still didn't say what precise assumptions you make on $E$. You talk about a convex open set $\Omega$, but $E$ is just an infinite-dimensional vector space, no topology specified. // I still think the reference to chapter III, §5 of Bessaga-Pelczynski is quite relevant and will be helpful for getting a precise statement and argument. The technique developed there is nice and of a rather elementary nature.

Comment: @Martin: Thank you, I'll definitely look at the reference as soon as I get my hands on a copy. Sorry that I didn't make the assumptions more precise, I'll give some background here:
The case I'm interested in is where $E$ is a closed infinite dimensional subspace of the space $Vect(M)$ of all vector fields on a compact, closed manifold $M$. I'm guessing that $Vect(M)$ is a Hilbert space with inner product: $<X,Y>:=\sup_{p\in M} g_p(X(p),Y(p))$, where $g$ is a complete Riemannian-metric on $M$, right? If this is correct, then $E$ should be a Hilbert-space itself.

Comment: @Martin: Does the argument work in this setting? (For some more background, see my [question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/127843/contractibility-of-a-configuration-space) on MO.)

Comment: Thanks for providing the background. Are you sure that $\operatorname{Vect}(M)$ is complete? I think it isn't: if $M = S^1$ you get the $C^\infty$-functions on $S^1$ and this space is dense in $L^2(S^1)$, which is strictly larger. However, that's actually a plus, because then the rather elementary proposition 5.1 of Bessaga-Pelczynski applies and proves the stronger property that $E \setminus Q_m$ is homeomorphic to $E$. I made a scan for you: [page 1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Iyj8M.png) and [page 2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/G4o6M.png) and [I, Cor. 3.3](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ACFJP.png).

Comment: I think in order for your argument to work, you need to know that you have a countable basis for $E$ in a good sense, so that $\Phi$ actually maps $E$ into $E$ (both these things don't seem to be automatic since $\operatorname{Vect}(M)$ is not complete with respect to the inner product $\langle X, Y \rangle$). Provided you can show that this is the case, I think your argument is okay. It might be checkable in your specific problem, but all the checking is probably more tedious than the proof given in the scans.

Comment: @Martin: Wow, thanks a lot for the scans! I really appreciate your help! The proof in the scans is very nice. Although I understand that $Vect(M)$ is not always complete (as your example shows), I don't yet see why $Vect(M)$ (resp. $E$) is always non-complete (under reasonable assumptions on $M$), which is needed for the proof in the scans. Do you know by any chance why or if this is the case?

Comment: It is not hard to write down a discontinuous vector field that can be approximated in the $L^2$-norm by smooth vector fields: e.g. a smooth vector field multiplied by the characteristic function of a compact embedded disk in a coordinate patch. This is discontinuous if the vector field doesn't vanish in a neighborhood of the disk.

Comment: In any case non-completeness is not a serious issue: A bit later in the section they prove using "basic sequence techniques" that on any infinite-dimensional normed space there is a non-complete continuous norm. This is then used to show that Proposition 5.1 holds for every infinite-dimensional normed space.

Comment: @Martin: Ah thank you, that sounds very good. I'll read the rest of the section as soon as I can.